# JavaScript post same name for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to upload in the database using pure javascript in my following input fields.

```js
var i = 2;
var id=1;
function addkid() {
    
   
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  console.log('my id cj '+id)
  
  div.innerHTML = 'Day' + id + ': <input type="text"  name="child_' + id + '"/>' + '<input type="button" class="submit_but" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remkid(this)" value="-" />';
  //div.innerHTML = 'Day' + id + ': <input type="text" name="child_' + id + '"/>' + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />' + ' <input type="button" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remkid(this)" value="-" />';
    //  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
   id++;
}

function remkid(div) {
  document.getElementById('kids').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////

var i = 1; 
var idd = 1;
function addmen() {
 
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  console.log('my id cj '+idd);
  //var id = i;
 // alert(id);
  div.innerHTML = 'img' + idd + ': <input type="file"  name="child_' + id + '"/>' + '<input type="button" class="submit_but" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remmen(this)" value="-" />';
  //div.innerHTML = 'Day' + id + ': <input type="text" name="child_' + id + '"/>' + ' <input type="button" id="add_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />' + ' <input type="button" id="rem_kid()_' + id + '" onclick="remkid(this)" value="-" />';
  document.getElementById('menand').appendChild(div);
   idd++;
}

function remmen(div) {
  document.getElementById('menand').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
}
```

```html
Title:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br/>
  <div id="kids">
    Day/s:
    <!--<input type="text" name="child_1">-->
    <input type="button" class="submit_but"  id="add_kid()_1" onclick="addkid()" value="Add tour day" /><br>
  </div>
   <div id="menand">
    Img/s:
    <!--<input type="file" name="img">-->
    <input type="button" class="submit_but" id="add_kid()_1" onclick="addmen()" value="Add tour Image" /><br>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" class="submit_but" onclick="saveroute()">
  </div>
```

I want to know how to upload this multiple same name input field into the database. I'm never doing this type of code in before. please help solve my problem

Comment: You need array as input name like `name="file[]"`

Comment: Please refer to this thread: https://code-boxx.com/post-array-html-form/#:~:text=To%20send%20an%20array%2C%20we,the%20same%20name%20as%20required.

Comment: Your input name should represent array holder like
  <input type="text" name="name[]">,  and when you post it then you can iterate it as a array using for loop or foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

The id is an unique identifier. The means that your 'id=add_kid()_1' can't repeat for more than one . The class attribute can repeat. In this case, you'll use the class="submit_but" to catch the two input tags.

Then, the first step is extract the info. There's only two inputs to extract info from and they have the tag in common: "submit_but".

```
const infoElements = document.querySelector('.submit_but');
```

infoElemnts contains all nodes with class="submit_but".

**Here your answer pt1**
If you wanna store the info of inputs in an array:

```
 const infoValues = infoElements.map((element) => {
        return element.value;
    }
```

Now, infoValues has all inputs values. You can do all this process with yours childs inputs that will be created.

```
 div.innerHTML = '<input class="dayTour"></input>' 
 div.innerHTML = '<input class="whatever"></input>' 

 const dayTourElements = document.querySelector('.dayTour');
 
 const dayTourValues = dayTourElements.map((element) => {
        return element.value;
 }
```

**Here your answer pt2**

I don't how you wanna save this, but for simple approach you can simple write it to your local storage into a '.txt' file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Here tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp